# Getting first ul child and do function

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, html-lists

I have this script: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24mD8/3/)

If you type something you will get Google suggestions. I would like to get the value (on keyUp) of the first li item (child) with jQuery and then do some function.

I tried this:

```
select: function(e, ui){
    $("#term").val(ui.first.item.value);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be little more descriptive?

Comment: Do a function with the value of the first li item of the drop down. Is it clear now?

Comment: What do you mean by "Do a function"?

Comment: Why the first listed suggestion/option and not the selected one? :P

Comment: I mean my function which is not important to discuss

Comment: What about the [autoFocus](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus) option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're aiming for is to use the `open` property on the autocomplete field:

```
open: function(e, ui) {
  var feelingLucky = $('.ui-autocomplete li:first-child a').html();
  // do something
}
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/f8hJu/)

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much already have it:

```
select: function(e, ui){
    $("#term").autocomplete('search', ui.item.value);
    alert(ui.item.value);
    doSomething(ui.item.value)
}
```

unless i'm not understanding what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the console to view the objects properties/members.

`console.log(ui);` showed;

```
Object
item: Object
    label: "olive garden"
    value: "olive garden"
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

`ui.item.value` is set to "*olive garden*" and the `ui` object doesn´t contain any "first" property.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to get there by getting the ul element and then the first li

```
$("ul li:first-child")
```